# Android - DialogFragment blocking edit text focus in base activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

Good day.

I have an android application and I have a custom listView. Upon clicking the customListView I change the layout of the selected row (I change the last 2 column to editTexts), and I show a dialogFragment (which has an editText). Here is my code:

The onItemClickListener:

```
resultListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {

        //first I move the selected row to the top of the listView
        resultListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(pos, 0);

        //then I disable selection of the listView to limit user action
        resultListView.setScrollContainer(false);
        resultListView.setClickable(false);
        resultListView.setEnabled(false);

        //I try to make the row still enabled and clickable
        view.setClickable(true);
        view.setEnabled(true);


        //TODO - set clickstate = 0 is base/default state

        for(SearchResultListViewItem row : results){
            row.setClickState(1); //state 1 = dim
        }

        SearchResultListViewItem rowItem = results.get(pos);
        rowItem.setClickState(2); //state 2 - clicked state

        //in my CustomAdapter, I handle the clickState in the getView method
        //basically, the change happens when click state is 2, the last 2 columns become editText
        adapter.updateResults(results);

        //I removed a lot of unrelated code in here
        ItemDialog itemDialog = new ItemDialog();

        //I set various variables here

        itemDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "");

    };

});
```

This is the onCreateDialog Method. As you can see below, I set various properties such as `setCancelable`, `setCancelOnTouchOutside`, and window Flags for Modal.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());  

    //set width height here
    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 4/5;
    int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;       
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

    //set other features here
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  

    //make sure that the dialog persists through certain events
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View layout2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_dialog, null);

    dialog.setContentView(layout2);  
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialog);

    //set window properties such as modal, dim, and position
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

    window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
    params.x = 50;
    params.y = y;

    params.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());

    window.setAttributes(params);

    //edited out a lot of extra code

    dialog.show();  


    return dialog;  
}
```

And if necessary, here is the code in the `getView` method in my Custom BaseAdapter that handles when I change the `clickState` to 2:

```
//the if condition checks if the clickstate is < 2, if < 2, do the default and dim state
//click state of 2 means that I use the other row layout which has 2 editTexts 
else{
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_result_inflate, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.itemView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dialogItemName);
    holder.itemView.setText(listData.get(position).getItemName());
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66B2FF"));

    holder.priceView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    holder.priceView.setText(listData.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.priceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66B2FF"));

    holder.discountView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discount);
    holder.discountView.setText(listData.get(position).getDiscount());
    holder.discountView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66B2FF"));

    holder.qtyIn = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qtyInput);
    holder.qtyIn.setText(listData.get(position).getQtyInput());
    holder.qtyIn.setFocusable(true);
    holder.qtyIn.setClickable(true);

    holder.discIn = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discInput);
    holder.discIn.setText(listData.get(position).getDiscInput());
    holder.discIn.setFocusable(true);
    holder.discIn.setClickable(true);

    return convertView;
}
```

As you can see, I tried to enable the necessary rows as much as possible. However, it seems that the DialogFragment is blocking it.

I also tried to comment out the

```
        resultListView.setScrollContainer(false);
        resultListView.setClickable(false);
        resultListView.setEnabled(false);
```

block of code in my `OnItemClickListener` but to no avail.

The funny/interesting thing about this is that I am able to select the editTexts in the new row, I can see the focus shift, however, the soft keyboard does not appear at all. The soft keyboard only appears when I click the editText inside the DialogFragment. Even switching focus from the EditText in the dialog Fragment to the one in the list view doesn't enable me to put input inside the EditText in the rows.

If it's conflict between the EditText in the background/base activity (the one in the rows) and the EditText in the DialogFragment, then I hope there's a way to properly switch focus as I cannot resort to removing either of them.

Does anyone have an idea on how to work around this? Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Edit: I removed the EditText in the DialogFragment and it still doesn't work.